# is there a benefit to using function.apply(obj) vs function(obj)

Tags: javascript

in javascript we can perform operations on an object in a few different ways. My question is primarily about the 2 ways described below:

```
function op() {
  this.x;
  this.y;
  etc..
}

op.apply(someObject);
```

or

```
function op(ob) {
  ob.x;
  ob.y;
  etc..
}

op(someObject);
```

both of these seem to get the same end result. are there scenarios where using one has advantages over using the other?

advantages can be things that make the code:

1. more flexible
2. more declarative
3. easier to maintain
4. simpler

or other advantages I haven't thought of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first (using `apply` to set `this`) is a bit more obscure. If one looks just at the function definition, one will spend some time wondering what `this` is supposed to be. If by any chance, the function is defined as a method, then naturally one would assume that `this` is supposed to refer to the object it is defined on.

The second variant (without `apply`) is clearer: the parameter has a name that can (should) reveal its role, while `this` can remain available for when the function is assigned to an object property, and it is called as a method on that object.

As a side note: `apply` allows (and expects) the (other) arguments to be passed as an array. This used to be a "plus" in some scenarios, but has become less significant now that the spread syntax is available.

Comment: that's more or less what i was thinking too